# How to activate more ruby rules?

Tags: ruby, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to analyze my ruby project via SonarQube 5.6.x. There is currently no official support for the Ruby language from SonarSource. Therefore I installed the community driven [SonarQube Ruby Plugin](https://github.com/GoDaddy-Hosting/ruby-sonar-plugin).

After having a look at the quality profile, I found out that there are only 6 rules activated. How can I improve the quality profile for ruby?

Comment: yes, I am referring to quality profile for ruleSet against which code gets scanned while doing sonarqube analysis.